# How to pass multiple variables to Go HTML template

Tags: go, go-templates

I am new to golang. I would like to pass multiple variables to html.
So I have a type like:

```
type Variables struct { 
    UserNames    []string  
    Checks       []string
}
```

pagevarible with passed the correct values

```
var PageVars Variables
    PageVars = Variables{
        UserNames: ulist,
        Checks: check,
    }
    log.Println("ulist",ulist)
    err = tpl.Execute(w, PageVars) //execute the template and pass it to index page
    if err != nil { // if there is an error
        log.Print("template executing error: ", err) //log it on terminal
    }
```

And I want to pass both UserNames and Checks to html template, something like:

```
{{range .UserNames .Checks}}
{{.UserNames}}: <input type="checkbox" name="email" value={{. UserNames}} {{.Checks}}/><br />
{{end}}
```

But it didn't work out.
Can anyone correct my syntax?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Range with an index variable, use that index to get the check:

```
{{range $i, $user := .UserNames}}
{{$check := index $.Checks $i}}
{{$user}}: <input type="checkbox" name="email" value={{$user}} {{$check}}/><br />
{{end}}
```

Range sets the cursor `.` to successive values of the slice. Use `$` to reference the `Checks` field in the argument to the template.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/1ZtJ_bspDzu)

Answer (score 3):

When you reference fields via `.` inside a range, its expecting that to be a field on the item being ranged, so in this case

```
{{range .UserNames}}
{{$check := .Checks}}
```

Its looking for a Checks field on the current instance in the Usernames list. If checks is separate to that (as it appears in your PageVars), then you can use the `$` reference to the top level object, e.g.

```
{{range .UserNames}}
{{$check := $.Checks}}
```

You didn't post the code executing the template, but make sure you're checking the error returned from it.

Comment: Thanks, UserNames and Checks they have the same parents and both of them is array with same length. Actually I want to range them together, but don't know how. If I do {{$check := $.Checks}}  it will return me the string "$check", not "checked" as I wanted. Do you know how to correct it?

Comment: easiest would be to transform the 2 lists into a list of structs with 2 fields.

Comment: Could you please have a check in this case I already passed PageVars to html, how could I call it from html?